# errorlist this field is required

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

```
form = AuthorForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES, self.request.user)

class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['file','user']`


class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='authors/')
```

With above configuration, I get the error

```
<tr><th><label for="user">User:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul><select id="user" name="user" required
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="2">admin</option>
<option value="3">user2</option>
```

I do not want to set blank=True in user field. I've passed request.user to ModelForm and I want the same to be stored in db but it's not working as expected.

May I know how to pass request.user to ModelForm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
form = AuthorForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES, self.request.user)
```

You can't pass `self.request.user` to the form like this unless you have overwritten the form's `__init__` method.

You should remove the `user` field from the form,

```
class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['file',]
```

and then set the user in the view's `form_valid` method.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    return super(MyView, self).form_valid(form)
```

If your view doesn't call `form_valid`, then change the code that saves the form to use `commit=False`, and set the user there.

```
author = form.save(commit=False)
author.user = self.request.user  # request.user in a function-based view
author.save()
```

Comment: Thanks. that resulted in `sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: myapp_author.user_id`

Comment: It shouldn't give that error, since you have set the user with `form.instance.user = self.request.user`. This approach is [from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user). There isn't enough information in your question to show why you're getting the error.

Comment: Second solution(to add user and saving later) worked. As per doc, form_valid belongs to CreateView and my form was inherited from ModelForm. learning Django. Thanks.

Comment: `form_valid` method belongs on the *view*, not your form. Since you have `self.request.user` in your question I assumed you were using a class based view.